# four parameter beta distribution in R

Tags: r, beta-distribution

Is there a built-in function to calculate a four parameter beta distribution in R? I.e., the distribution with two shape parameters and two boundary parameters so that it's not bounded [0,1]?

I made my own but curious if this functionality exists already. No need to reinvent the wheel.

```
shp1 <- 20
shp2 <- 5
X <- seq(0,1,length.out = 100)
Y <- dbeta(x = X,shape1 = shp1, shape2 = shp2)
plot(X,Y)
# scaled between two boundaries
dbeta4param <- function(x,shp1,shp2,bnd1,bnd2){
  mask = (x>=bnd1 & x<=bnd2)
  xScale = (x-bnd1)/(bnd2-bnd1)
  mask * dbeta(xScale,shape1=shp1,shape2=shp2)/(bnd2-bnd1)
}
bnd1 <- 2
bnd2 <- 4
X2 <- seq(bnd1,bnd2,length.out = 100)
Y2 <- dbeta4param(x=X2, shp1 = shp1, shp2 = shp2, bnd1 = bnd1, bnd2 = bnd2)
plot(X2,Y2)
```

Comment: are you talking of the [generalized beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution#Generalization)?

Comment: Ah. Yes it is. Thanks.

Comment: look at `library(GB2)` the function `dgb2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CRAN Task View: Probability Distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) is always a good resource about where to find various `R` probability distributions. According to it, you should use the [extraDistr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extraDistr/index.html) package (`extraDistr::rnsbeta` for example).

Comment: Indeed. I was looking for the generalization as @Onyambu commented. I called the special function beta() to make my own function: `dbeta4param <- function(x,shp1,shp2,bnd1,bnd2){
   ((x-bnd1)^(shp1-1) * (bnd2 - x)^(shp2-1)) / ((bnd2 - bnd1)^(shp1+shp2-1) * beta(shp1,shp2))
}` . And indeed `extraDistr::rnsbeta` looks quite similar and does what I want. Thanks.